# R: Create every possible combinations of given columns

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I have a data that corresponds to df. df shows the source and destination and the longitudes and latitudes of this sources and destinations.

I want to use df to generate df1. df1 gives all possible combinations of source and destination and while doing so combines the appropriate source and destination longitudes and latitudes.

```
Source <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
Destination <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
Source_Latitude <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
Source_Longitude <- c(-1, -2, -3, -4)
Dest_Latitude <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
Dest_Longitude <- c(-1, -2, -3, -4)
df <- data.frame(Source, Source_Latitude, Source_Longitude, Destination,Dest_Latitude,Dest_Longitude)


Source <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B","B","B","B", "C","C","C","C", "D","D","D","D")
Destination <- c("A", "B", "C", "D","A", "B", "C", "D","A", "B", "C", "D","A", "B", "C", "D")
Source_Latitude <- c(1,1,1,1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4)
Source_Longitude <- c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-2,-2,-2,-2,-3,-3,-3,-3,-4,-4,-4,-4)
Dest_Latitude <- c(1, 2, 3, 4,1, 2, 3, 4,1, 2, 3, 4,1, 2, 3, 4)
Dest_Longitude <- c(-1, -2, -3, -4,-1, -2, -3, -4,-1, -2, -3, -4,-1, -2, -3, -4)
df1 <- data.frame(Source, Source_Latitude, Source_Longitude, Destination,Dest_Latitude,Dest_Longitude)
```

I tried using `crossing()` and `expand.grid()` without any success

Comment: Why was the `expand.grid` approach not successful? Can you show us what you tried, and how the result differed from your expectation?

Comment: @dario Because that would attach a source_latitude of e.g. 2 to a Source A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
all_combination<-   expand.grid(Source=df$Source, Destination=df$Destination)%>%
  inner_join(select(df, contains("Source")), by = "Source") %>%
  inner_join(select(df, contains("Dest")), by = "Destination")) %>%
  distinct()
```

This worked for me. Took a while to figure out how to use the `expand.grid()`function.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

expand.grid(Source = Source, Destination = Destination) %>% 
  inner_join(select(df, contains("Source")), by = "Source") %>%
  inner_join(select(df, contains("Dest")), by = "Destination")) %>% 
  select(contains("Source"), contains("Dest")) %>% View()
```

As an additional observation, although the code works, I don't think it's the best to keep sources and destinations in the same dataframe. Because the number of sources and destinations may be different. It would probably be best to have one data frame for each, and adapt the code accordingly.